# equivalent implementation to com.google.common.util.concurrent

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Is there any concurrency implementation lib like guava? For some reason I'm not able to use it.  Basically I'm trying to use `ListenableFuture`

Comment: Have you looked at java.util.concurrent yet?

Comment: If you're not able to use Guava, why would you be able to use another library? Why don't you tell us what the problem is with Guava?

Comment: thank you for reminding me azurefrog, looking it.

Comment: "For some reason I'm not able to use it." What reason?

Comment: Sorry for very brief question, we had customized platform, and my application is going to be deployed on it and it has very old google collection which is conflicting with guava while platform boot, and i have no control over the platform to upgrade the library

Comment: you should update your question with these details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [using Guava with ProGuard](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingProGuardWithGuava) to repackage Guava with only the subset you need.  Alternatively you could relocate the Guava packages using [the shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html) if you're using maven or [jarjar](https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) if you're using ant.

Answer (score 0):

Look at  `com.github.rfqu.df4j.CompletableFuture` in (my) [df4j-core](https://github.com/rfqu/df4j/blob/master/df4j-core) project. If you find a bug, or need an enhancement, submit an issue to the project and I'll fix it.

Comment: new version available https://github.com/rfqu/df4j2/tree/master/df4j-core , CompletableFuture renamed to org.df4j.core.func.Promise.

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for sharing your lib, but i couldn't use it in my application(for now i have managed with java.util.concurrent), but certainly would like to try it